# Check for moon phase with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to check what phase the moon is in, on any given night. I know that every 7 in-game days is a full cycle and the fuller the moon is the higher the difficulty of mobs and such. I'm working on a simple datapack that sometimes makes mobs spawn as stronger mobs, and thought it would be cool to have them spawn more often on nights with a full moon and not at all on new moon nights.

So TL;DR is basically: can I check what phase the moon is on with commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a scoreboard objective. I called it 'testing' here:

```
/scoreboard objectives add testing dummy
```

Then whenever you want to check, run this command chain:

```
/execute store result score day testing run time query day
/scoreboard players set operator testing 8
/scoreboard players operation day testing %= operator testing
```

This will get the current day count (`/time query day`) and store it in a virtual player score `day`. Then it will get the 'modulus 8' of that number, which means it'll get the remainder when dividing the number by 8.

Doing this makes the day count loop from 0 -> 7. You can then do certain commands on certain 'weekdays' with the command `/execute if score day testing matches <x> run <y>` where x is the day and y is the command to be ran.

0 is a full moon, and 4 is a new moon.